# Settings view in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

So I am working on a simple weather app and I want to add a view where the user can switch between Celsius and Fahrenheit. How would I do this? How would I make it so the switches on that screen would effect the rest of the app? I really don't know where to start with this one. Anything that I have found so far has either been outdated or been using the iOS settings and I don't want to do that. Any help would be great.

Comment: Start with a simpler problem. Show us the code to open a view which displays a temperature in any units.

Comment: Right now I have the temperature displaying on a few labels and how I move between the views is just a bar button

Comment: post some of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a view with a switch on it, you could update a flag in a part of your app called `UserDefaults` documented [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults). Then, when you visit parts of your app that display the temperature, you can check the flag you have set to see if the user prefers Celsius or Fahrenheit and show the correct view accordingly.

```swift
UserDefaults.standard.set(false, forKey: "celsius")
let preference = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "celcius")
if preference == true {
     //user prefers Celsius
} else {
     //user prefers Fahrenheit
}
```

Comment: Could something like having a segue going between the 2 views work? Like set the defaults when the app launches and pass the values to the settings and have them then be passed back and overwrite the defaults

Comment: You will have to make some of these design decisions based on what is best for your app but as a starting place, you could add code in `viewDidLoad` to check the `UserDefaults` and decide which values to show in your UI there. The defaults are persistent so you do not need to set them every time the app launches. Using a segue to get to the settings view should work fine, just make sure that when you pop back to the previous view, you might have to check the defaults again to make sure that you are showing the most up to date data.